# Hyphen in regular expression in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

There is this regexp in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^collection/([^/_]+)games/$ some.php?coll=$1 [L]
```

It works fine for url's like "/collection/somegames/"
But i want the rule to accept these url's: "/collection/some-games/" to be redirected to "some.php?coll=some"
I change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^collection/([^/_]+)-games/$ some.php?coll=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^collection/([^/_\-]+)-games/$ some.php?coll=$1 [L]
```

None of the above helped.
What is the solution?

Comment: Your first regular expression already matches `/collection/some-games/`

Comment: yes, it does, but $1="-games"

Comment: oops. that is what i meant. that hyphen is the part of the variable

Comment: So you don't want the hyphen in `$1`? Probably should have mentioned in the question; you only talk about wanting the rule to accept the example URL `/collection/some-games/`, which it does. Answer coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^collection/([^/_]+?)-?games/$ some.php?coll=$1 [L]
```

There you go.

Comment: I have [actually tested](http://rewrite.dev.lanzz.org/collection/some-games/) the answer, so I know for a fact that it handles `collection/some-games` as well. Consider enabling [rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (method differs between versions) and providing the log generated for a `collection/some-games` request.